# Is there any way to access to Arduino ESP8266 server not within same WIFI?

Tags: arduino, hosting, esp8266

I'm developing a server on arduino ESP8266.
I know that to access the server on arduino ESP8266, I have to connect same WIFI with arduino.

But I want to access the server not in WIFI same on arduino, I mean I want to connect to the Arduino server remotly from a distance 
like a Amazon Web Service EC2.

I do not know about Arduino because I'm a beginner. Help me.

Comment: downvoted because of not helpfull for this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your server post to or read from an public visible server (like [AWS IOT](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-platform/how-it-works/)). Then you can access this information anywhere on the internet. Here is an [example](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Using-AWS-IoT-Serivce/), search a bit there is lots of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Arduino itself but with your network configuration. You can make it accessible from all over the world at the extreme cost of giving up your LAN security.

The possibilities depend on the capabilities of your network equipment (router, ISP-modem/router...).

You should ask you question elsewhere (like https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).